# How to convert a Webapp(implemented in jsp) to Mobile Webapp

Tags: web-applications, mobile

I have a webapp implemented in JSPs and hosted in tomcat.

How can I convert it into a mobile app and make it compatible to view it on a small mobile device ?

Please suggest a tool.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to understand that for a mobile application that runs on every device it needs to be a client side webapp, so only HTML, CSS and Javascript. If you have that you can let http://build.phonegap.com pull from a repository and build packages for every platform.

If you only want Android i suggest you take a look here: http://news.softpedia.com/news/Jetty-Servlet-Ported-to-Google-Android-81049.shtml

Comment: why was this downvoted? He asked for a tool, i provided one?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to is to make your web app support mobile browsers - the current state of the art here is [Responsive Design](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Responsive_web_design).

Users can add links to your website to their home screens on mobile devices, so it will be available without opening a browser and remembering a URL. This gives you the widest range of compatibility, but the drawback is that the look and feel will always be "website", not "native app"; you also can't take advantage of native capabilities of the device.

If you want a native look and feel, you have to build native apps; those apps can take advantage of services exposed by your existing JSP app (though you have to build those services of course).

This gives you a native look and feel, and access to device capabilities, but requires significant effort.

Finally, you can use hybrid tools like Phonegap, calatrava and Appcelerator; these allow you to "build once, deploy on multiple devices", often using HTML & JavaScript - but they are not [without problems](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/CrossPlatformMobile.html).

Answer (score 0):

The simple solution would be, adding mobile display tags such as "view port" to the output page. It worked for me.

Venu